# Why Do AWS Lambda Layers Behave Differently When I Add Multiple?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have an aws lambda function which has dependency on my layer, `dep_1`. This `dep_1` layer is built from a zip called `dep.zip` in s3. The structure of `dep_1` is:

```
dep.zip
|
|-python
   |
   |-pandas
   |-pandas.1.03.dist-info
   |-pkg_2
   |-pkg_2.version.dist-info
   |-pkg_3
   |-...
```

In my lambda function handler file `my_lambda.py`, I use `import pandas as pd` and it fails, saying `"Unable to import module 'my_lambda': No module named 'pandas'"`

I had followed the official documentation, yet it fails. [Documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

I happened across a fix. When I simply add another lambda layer with a later merge order, then the first layer starts working and I can import the modules of it. The contents of the second lambda are throwaway; I don't need them, but I make sure they don't interfere with the contents of my first lambda. So in other words, the second layer contains a module that has nothing to do with `pandas`, yet only after I add it can I import `pandas`.

What is happening in aws' merging of the layers to get this working? Do I have my directory structure correct in layer one? I can't inspect it in the lambda, because aws puts all the modules in /opt.